# How to have component re-render after its props change in Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

My component is simple:

```html
<template>
  <btn :color="color" @click="toggleColor">{{btnmsg}}</btn>
</template>

<script>
  import { Btn } from 'chico'
  export default {
    name: 'AButton',
    components: {
      Btn
    },
    data() {
      return {
        btnmsg: 'Legia pany',
        colors: [
          'blue', 'black', 'green', 
          'orange', 'teal', 'cyan', 
          'yellow', 'white'
        ],
        color: 'red'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleColor() {
        this.color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(this.colors.length))];
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `<Btn>` from the ChicoFamily goes something like this:

```html
<template>
  <button :is="tag" :class="[className, {'active': active}]" :type="type" :role="role">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import classNames from 'classnames';
export default {
  props: {
    tag: {
      type: String,
      default: "button"
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "default"
    },
    //...it takes a lot of props...
  },
  data() {
    return {
      className: classNames(
        this.floating ? 'btn-floating' : 'btn',
        this.outline ? 'btn-outline-' + this.outline : this.flat ? 'btn-flat' : this.transparent ? '' : 'btn-' + this.color,
        //...classes derived from these props...
      ),
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

It's a button that, when clicked, should change its color. Clicking it indeed changes the prop passed, but does not re-render the button in the new color.

Why does passing a different prop not re-render the button?

The `<Btn>` takes its color from Bootstrap classes deriving from the prop. Could it be that the Btn gets the proper prop, but the `className` mechanic does not catch up?

Comment: What is that *chico*'s  **Btn** component that you are importing ?

Comment: Added some code for it! As you can see, it's a wrapper for a button taking in a lot of props for proper styling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a re-rendering problem– the component is indeed re-rendering when the prop changes. The problem is that the re-render does it no good, because you set the color as an *initial value* in `data`, and not as a `computed` property that gets re-evaluates when data changes.

The way you did it, the `className` will be set once when the instance will is created, and never again.

In order to make the `className` re-evaluate each time you change one of the props passed in, you will have to make a `computed` property out of it, like this:

Btn component:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    [...]
  },
  computed: {
    className() {
      return classNames(
        this.floating ? 'btn-floating' : 'btn',
        this.outline ? 'btn-outline-' + this.outline : this.flat ? 'btn-flat' : this.transparent ? '' : 'btn-' + this.color
      );
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Setting a :key on the component is the best way to force Vue to re-render the component. If you require the component to be re-rendered, simply modify the value of the key, and Vue will re-render it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it, the className will be set once when the instance is created, and never again.

You should use computed for className.